# Images are not responsive

Tags: css, responsive

Images are not resizing properly, can't figure it out

If you visit [melrosegirl.com](http://melrosegirl.com), you will notice three set of images;

1. Image slider
2. Smaller images
3. Second main images

Currently all my images are 1920 × 720 pixels (not sure if it's the proper size).

If you will look at the images on different devices are not sizing properly for different screen devices.

The issues are;
1. Slider images for some reason have a bottom grey border
2. Second large image doesn't scale properly and it's getting squeezed.

I have a feeling it's an issue with the CSS code - can you please assist? =)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website / demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Add background-size: cover; for 200px - 480px screen

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 200px)
.slide1 .item-slick1 {
  height: 207px !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

`!important` because you have other background-size values with `!important` marked.

Comment: thank you.

Should I remove anything for the main css file or just add section?
It seems that it affects only the slider images, what about the main second image?

Comment: Looks like you have added everything. You could just add `background-size: cover !important;` at line 1352 in custom.css